# Avoiding "app" folder in Brunch

Tags: web, frontend, brunch

I want to use Brunch in a project with this structure:

```
root/        
|-src/ 
|--assets/ 
|---js/ 

|-bower_components/ 
|--...stuff... 

|-dist/      
|--...output stuff... 

|-bower.json  
|-package.json 
|-config.coffee
```

Nevertheless, it seems that Brunch is ignoring anything is outside the "app" directory.
In other world, it does not work:

```coffee
  conventions:
    assets: /src\/assets\//
  paths:
    public: 'dist'
    watch: ['src']
  files:
    javascripts:
      joinTo:
        'dist/output.js': /^src\/js/
```

There is an option to set the name of the "app" folder?

My environment: Brunch 1.8.7, Node 0.12.2, Windows 7

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `paths.watch`. You should be using `paths.watched`.